# Why bibtex repeat "series" and "volume" in Proceedings?

Tags: bibtex

When writing the following proceeding:

```
@inproceedings{BCM74,
author={Boesch, F. T.  and Chen,  S.  and  McHugh, J. A. M.},
title={On covering the points of a graph with point disjoint paths},
booktitle={Graph Theory and Combinatorics},
year={1974},
pages={201--212},
publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
volume = {406},
series={Lecture Notes in Mathematics}
}
```

I get this:

*Boesch, F. T., S. Chen, and J. A. M. McHugh. 1974. “On covering the points of a graph with point disjoint paths.” In Graph Theory and Combinatorics, Vol. 406 of Lecture Notes in MathematicsVol. 406 of Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 201–212. Springer Berlin Heidelberg.*

The series and the volume are repeated twice, do you have any idea on how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also make a minimal example that uses this, might be relevant to know which bibtex style was used. Not seeing anything wrong with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I have no problems compiling the following code (including your bib entry).

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@inproceedings{BCM74,
  author    = {Boesch, F. T.  and Chen,  S.  and  McHugh, J. A. M.},
  title     = {On covering the points of a graph with point disjoint paths},
  booktitle = {Graph Theory and Combinatorics},
  year      = {1974},
  pages     = {201--212},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  volume    = {406},
  series    = {Lecture Notes in Mathematics},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe]

Please run my code on your computer and check the output.  If it compiles like mine, copy my MWE and change it accourding to the code you are using calling your bibliography ...

**Update:**

If you check the zip file you told me in your comment you can see, that this zip file contains several `*.sty` files, the `tPRS.bst` and the `tPRS2e.cls` file.  Copy only the `*.bst` and the `*.cls` file into a new directory, copy your TeX code too, change class `article` to `tPRS2e` and compile.  Then I get the wished result.

At last I guess the error comes from the in the zip file included file `natbib.sty`.  So if you need the definitions of the other `sty` files, just copy all files from the zip file and delete the copied `natbib.sty`.  Then the `natbib` definitions of your TeX distribution will be used.

Comment: In fact, I am using the latex template of this journal: http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=tprs20&page=instructions , they have a specific style for bibliography (\bibliographystyle{tPRS}). So, I cannot use your MWE.

Comment: I have all the references in a file .bib and not in the file .tex. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 also.  With documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} it works, but when using \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{tPRS2e} I had the same problem.I think the problem is inside the style file.